# Every positive real number is the infinite sum of terms in $\{0,1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x$ be a positive real number.  Is there a sequence $(x_i)\in \{0\}\cup \{1/n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ such that $x=\sum_{i=0} ^\infty x_i ^2$ ?

It seems to me that you could recursively define the sequence by looking at the difference between $x$ and the sum of previously defined terms.  Then add a sufficiently small $1/n$ that gets you closer to, but not greater than, $x$.

But I think you have to be a little more careful than that, because the series could converge to a number $<x$.

Is it possible?

Comment: Every real number has a sequence of rationals that converges to it, and indeed this is possible so as you may use $\frac{1}{n}$ for a given $n$ multiple times.

Comment: I don't see exactly how the first statement implies the second.  Could you give some details please?

Comment: Your title and first sentence are quite different.  The title implies that you can use each fraction only once, while the first sentence seems to allow using one multiple times.  The first sentence also has $x_i$ squared in the sum.  The answer to both is yes.

Comment: @RossMillikan sorry, it was difficult to put everything in the title, and I also need to get some sleep!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. It's not actually a different problem than if you remove the square from the sum, as you can just add a number to itself several times. $\frac{1}{n^2}$ added to itself $n$ times produces $\frac{1}{n}$!

This reduces it to the well known problem called [Egyptian Fractions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction). Every real number has a way to represent it as the sum of the reciprocals of integers without repeats even!

To see that you can always get to $x$ and not get stuck lower, assume that you can only sum to $x'<x$ when you try to sum go $x$. Let $M>\frac{1}{x-x'}$. Then inserting $\frac{1}{M}$ at the beginning of your sum produces a larger sum still less than $x$. In this manner we can surpass any number smaller than $x$ but not pass $x$ so $x$ is the least upper bound and limit of the sum

Comment: it seems to me that you can get arbitrarily large numbers.  Note that $x_i=1$ is possible, and you can repeat terms.

Comment: @ForeverMozart are you allowed repeats then?

Comment: I believe that is what he's saying, yes.

Comment: @Stella yes ,,,

Comment: @ForeverMozart edited

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm that will construct an example of the desired sequence:

For $k\in{0,1,...}$,

Find minimum $n$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^k x_k-\frac{1}{n^2}>0$, add that as $x_{k+1}$ to your sum.

This is not hard to prove that it converges to the desired positive real number (hint, it's monotone increasing (strict unless you have partial sum$=x$) and eventually within every neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: ok so it is important to choose the minimum.  I'll try that.

Comment: That is not strictly necessary, but if you don't then you need some way to ensure that it really does eventually get within every neighborhood of $x$, and why make it any harder than necessary?